# mysql stored proc if else with select not working

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me get started with creating this stored procedure?  I'm just learning and I can't figure out why this doesn't work.  I Know it's something simple but I can't find any examples that show what is wrong.

Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
Line 7, column 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `su_verify_1`(IN inWks VARCHAR(15))
   If inWks = 'WN-IA15HXY41135' THEN
select 'no' as result, '3' as errorcode, 'This is a test' as message;
ELSE
   select 'yes' as result;
END IF;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: See: [14.1.16 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and [21.1 Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html), they will be useful in their learning process.

Comment: I have the impression it is due to your DELIMITER. It is common to "override" your delimiter when writing procedures (to avoid confusion between `;` and where your procedure ends). Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) for an example. Basicaly change your delimiter between declaration of procedures and when you finish change it back to `;`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes it was the delimiter, thanks.  feel free to post answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a delimiter other than a semicolon, so that MySQL knows where the procedure definition ends. As it stands, MySQL is currently seeing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `su_verify_1`(IN inWks VARCHAR(15))
   If inWks = 'WN-IA15HXY41135' THEN
select 'no' as result, '3' as errorcode, 'This is a test' as message;
```

With the rest of the lines treated as separate commands. Use the `DELIMITER` command to change this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `su_verify_1`(IN inWks VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    IF inWks = 'WN-IA15HXY41135' THEN
        SELECT 'no' AS result, '3' AS errorcode, 'This is a test' AS message;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'yes' AS result;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```